# Upload file outside the directory where script.php is present

Tags: php

My directory structure is like

```
  Root
    |---Includes
    |      |--script.php
    |
    |---uploads
    |
    |
    |---index.php
```

My index.php has a form that takes name and posts it to script.php file. I want to create folder in uploads older

script.php

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))

{
  mkdir('../uploads/'.$_POST['name']);
}
```

This runs fine when i move script.php to root folder and remove ../ but its not working when i use the code above

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: what error messages do you get? what permisions are set?

Comment: since the ``script.php`` is in your ``includes`` Dir. Do you include the upload script from a script in another directory or do you call it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

script.php is included by index.php and the current folder is Root, no matter where the included file is. Just use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the current folder for the included script. Your code should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
  mkdir( dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/uploads/'.$_POST['name']);
}
```

dirname is called two times to get the parent folder of Includes.

Another tip for security: do not use unchecked user input (_POST, _GET ..) for filenames. More information can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.php

Answer (score 0):

Try something such as the following (Assuming you run your website on Apache)

```
$destination = sprintf('%s/uploads/%s', getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT'), $_POST['name']);
```

Also I would avoid using the `$_POST` variable directly as you might want to have clean names for your folders.

If you want to use a relative path you can use

```
$destination = sprintf('%s/../uploads/%s', dirname(__FILE__), $_POST['name']);
```